# Intersection of a Family of Normal Subgroups of a Group G is also a Normal Subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I have this classic exercise to prove:

> If $ \{ N_i : i \in I \} $ is a family of normal subgroups of a group $ G $, then $ \bigcap_{i \in I} N_i $ is a normal subgroup of $ G $ too.

I am searching for a constructive reasoning.

**My solution is like as follows:**

Let's explicite the set of indices: $ I_n = \{ 1,2,...,n \} $. And let's give a name to the set mentioned above: $ F_i = \{ N_i : \forall i \in I_n, N_i < G \} $. **The crucial difference is that: we will suppose that elements of our set $ F $ are not normal subgroups of G.** Because we know that this enunciation is a valid property when $ N_i $ are ordinary subgroups.

Then define a function $ f : F_i \to \wp (G) $ such that, for $ i = 1 $ we have $ f(1) = N_1 $, and for $ i \ge 2 $, we have $ f(i) = N_i \bigcap f(N_{i-1}) $.

We can easily see that: $ \forall i \in I_n, f(i) \subset \wp (G) $, even better: $ f(i) < G $. As we can check: $ Dom(f) = F_i $ is a group on its own under the usual law of intersection; and the same for $ Im(f) = \wp (G) $.

So the tactic is to check if this function $ f $ is a *homomorphism of groups?* If it is so, then $ f $ preserves algebraic properties, and, as we started with the known conclusion **(the case where sets are not normal subgroups)** and constructed our correspondence, we can conclude **that the weaker property will be inherited.**

My need for help begins here: I don't know if $ f $ is well defined, AND, I couldn't prove that my function $ f $ is indeed a homomorphism.

Thank you all in advance for any advice and correction.

Comment: What is $\wp (G)$?

Comment: It is the Power Set of G. I couldn't find the appropriate symbol on Jax.

Comment: And what is the assumed group operation on $\wp(G)$?

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. You also make a mistake in the very first sentence: the indices needn't be countable. 


If each $N_i$ is normal, it follows that for each $g \in G$ and each $n_i \in N_i$, we have $gn_ig^{-1} \in N_i$. Hence if $n^{*} \in \bigcap N_i$ and $g \in G$, what can we say about $gn^{*}g^{-1}$?

Comment: Usual intersection. We need not Subsets of G be Subgroups. We need closure, associativity, etc. for Power Set of G to be a Group only.

Comment: Actually, I have no answers about what you ask MathematicsStudent1122 because I didn't use the definition to get there. I have already the proprety for ordinary subgroups. I said, if I define a homomorphism over it, and obviously normality being a weaker property than being any ordinary subgroup (which can be proved because reverse implication doesn't hold), then algebraically it would follow.

Comment: Observe that you've defined $\;F_i\;$ to be simply a set of subgroups. Unless you define an operation on that set it is **not** a group in itself...Thus the question whether $\;f\;$ is a groups homomorphism isn't appliable here...BTW, also the power set *isn't* naturally a group. You must define some operation on it and prove it owkrs to make the power set a group.

Comment: I stated that intersection of sets is the internal law (= binary operation, if you wish)... And about the power set being a group: actually this isn't a general case, but it doesn't matter. The idea is to construct a homomorphism to make inherit the preserved algebraic properties. So, power sets need only to be semigroup, but even better, they are already a monoid under intersection of sets...

Comment: If the intersection of groups is the group operation, then the whole group $\;G\;$ must be the unit element....but then what is the inverse for a non-trivial subgroup?! This doesn't work in the general case. And again: homomorphism is the general name for a map between *algebraic structures* that preserves the algebraic structure. There is no "homomorphism" is there is no algebraic structure (groups, rings, modules, vector spaces, etc.)

Comment: @DonAntonio you are echoing to my requests. I wish you would think about it this way: To construct a "litteral" homomorphism in aiming to preserve *algebraic structures* is what I want. My reasoning, in the path of your hints, led me to rethink and here's why: **We can prove the stronger statement with more general frame** ie. it is sufficient that $ H_i $ be *monoids* before *groups*. And I verified: When $ G $ is at least a monoid, and $ H_i $ are subsets of $ G $ which are *monoids*, then $ \cap H_i $ is itself a *monoid* with $ e_h = Id(H_i) $ for each. (...)

Comment: @DonAntonio (...) we don't need the inverse identity here, and the homomorphism is then well defined. But the 2nd question would be about my trouble about proving that within my $ f $ we have the property necessary for this to become concrete.

Answer (score 4):

Much simpler: take $\;x\in\bigcap_{i\in I} N_i\;$ , then for *any* $\;g\in G\;$ :

$$\forall\,i\in I\;,\;\;x^g:=gxg^{-1}\in N_i\implies x^g\in\bigcap _{i\in I}N_i\;\ldots$$

Observe that in the above it isn't assumed the index set $\;I\;$ is countable: that doesn't affect.